# Rendering a google chart using datastore data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-visualization

I am struggling to use data stored in datastore to render a google chart. At the moment I have queried the data model:

```
results = MyDataModel.query().fetch()
```

It is at this stage I am unsure what to do. For example, is it best to create a list in python like:

```
result_list = []
for result in results:
    result_list.append([result.employee, result.salary])
```

and then using Jinja2 templates pass it into an array table:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Employee Name', 'Salary'],
   {% for result in result_list %}
    {{result | safe}}
   {% endfor %},
  false);
```

Or is it best to dynamically add row data into a DataTable or is it best to query the data store directly?

Which ever way I try I am struggling to render anything at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would do it in your Jinja2 template as you describe in your question.  Is that not working for you?  Note that you can pass `results` to your template and that you don't need to create `result_list`.

Comment: Thanks @Kekito, I can't get it to work. Since posting I noticed a possible problem, I think I may need a "," after {{result | safe}} but I tried that and still nothing renders.

Comment: @Kekito - I forgot to mention, my query contains other fields like date_started etc so would it be better to filter these out of the query initially rather than creating result_list?

Comment: print for us the content of the array you are trying to input to the chart. its more of a google chart question than appengine. better yet make a fiddle, no need to debug in appengine which is harder.

Comment: As it stands, the content of the array is [['Test', 10], ['Another test', 9], ['Something else', 8]] but it renders to html like this   ['Employee Name', 'Salary'],
        
          ['Test', 10]
        
          ['Another test', 9]
        
          ['Something else', 8]
        ], so I assume as there is no "," between each output that is why the chart is not rendering?

Comment: Hi All, I have looked at all the options and they have all been really useful. Looking at JSFiddle has helped me to see that there was a slight issue with the codee of the jinja template. I also removed the whitespace in the html using "-". I would like to be able to upvote some of your suggestions but can't as the moment due to my points. Thanks everyone for your input

Comment: Ron, can you show an example of what finally worked for you? I am struggling with jinja2 on exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea with inserting the data into your Jinja2 template.  It looks like you are just not formatting your inputs to `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` correctly.  Note that one of your open square brackets ( [ ) is not closed.

Below is an example of how I have done this in case it helps you.  You can see it live [here](https://www.opavote.org/results/5654402576678912/1).

There is no point in creating the `result_list` array.  The `results` query is going to be processed regardless and it doesn't matter if it is being done in your handler or in the template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn("string", "Candidate");
data.addColumn("number", "Votes");
data.addColumn({type:"string", role:"tooltip"});
data.addColumn({type: "boolean", role:"certainty"});
data.addColumn("number", "Received");
data.addColumn({type:"string", role:"tooltip"});
data.addColumn("number", "Transferred");
data.addColumn({type:"string", role:"tooltip"});
data.addRows([["Vanilla", 110.000000, "Votes: 110", true, 0.000000, "Votes: 110", 0.000000, "Votes: 110"],["Chocolate", 117.000000, "Votes: 117", true, 0.000000, "Votes: 117", 0.000000, "Votes: 117"],["Strawberry", 80.000000, "Votes: 80", true, 0.000000, "Votes: 80", 0.000000, "Votes: 80"],["Chocolate Chip", 103.000000, "Votes: 103", true, 0.000000, "Votes: 103", 0.000000, "Votes: 103"],["Cookies and Cream", 118.000000, "Votes: 118", true, 0.000000, "Votes: 118", 0.000000, "Votes: 118"],["Exhausted", 0.000000, "Votes: 0", true, 0.000000, "Votes: 0", 0.000000, "Votes: 0"]]);
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({fractionDigits:0});
formatter.format(data, 1);
formatter.format(data, 3);
formatter.format(data, 5);
var options = {
width:'100%',
height:200,
legend:{position:"none"},
chartArea:{left:100,top:0,width:'100%',height:175},
hAxis:{maxValue:276},
isStacked:true,
colors:["#fcd050", "#87cf32", "#ef3638"],
};
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("282249-1"));
chart.draw(data, options);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Charts has the [Data Source Python Library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/gviz_api_lib) you could use to output to JSON on the server-side, to help make it easier to handle formatting. Using your result_list from above:

```
import gviz_api
datatable = gviz_api.DataTable([('Employee', 'string'), ('Salary', 'number')])
datatable.LoadData(result_list)
json = datatable.ToJSon()
# json is your jinja variable
```

And in your template:

```
var data = {{json|safe}};
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to load the data using AJAX, so you will need to have separated handler which will return JSON response.

By using Google's Polymer (guaranteed to work only in Chrome though) its pretty easy to render a chart from JSON:

```
<script src="//googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-chart/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="//googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-chart/components/google-chart/google-chart.html">
<google-chart
  options='{"title": "Super chart"}'
  data='/chart-data.json'>
</google-chart>
```

And your chart handler:

```
result = [['Employee', 'Salary']]
result += [[i.employee, i.salary] for i in MyDataModel.query().fetch(
  projection=['employee', 'salary'])]
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
self.response.write(json.dumps(result))
```

By using projection you will be billed only for "small" datastore operations -- it will consume only 1 read. Highly recommended to use for charts!

Comment: Why is it better to use AJAX rather than serving the needed data in the web page?

Comment: Because when you'll have more employers it will take more time to request all of them. This is still pretty heavy datastore request.